# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

```
update Quotation_T  set DOID= CASE 

              WHEN DOID IS NULL THEN CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))
              WHEN DOID LIKE '%'+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))+'%' THEN DOID       
              WHEN DOID IS NOT NULL THEN (DOID +','+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20)))
           END  
         where Quotation_T.QuotationID = 2 and Br_Code=1 and Item_Code=705
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Quotation_T.QuotationID`, `Br_Code` and `Item_Code` and `DOID`? Perhaps you could post the DDL of your table? *Also, you forgot to ask a question.* 

Comment: `CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))` -> `N'2'` ? and DOID seems to be int.

Comment: `select 1 + ','` also returns the same error. We can reasonably conclude that `DOID` is `int`, and so SQL Server is trying to do *maths* because of the `+` operator, not *string concatenation*. (You'll also get a similar error one you fix that error in your third line because your second `THEN` attempts to return `DOID` and so the type of the entire `CASE` expression is also determine to be `int`)

Answer (score 0):

You must convert DIOD to NVARCHAR in last when block.

```
update Quotation_T  set DOID= CASE     
                  WHEN DOID IS NULL THEN CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))
                  WHEN DOID LIKE '%'+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))+'%' THEN CAST(DOID AS NVARCHAR(20))
                  WHEN DOID IS NOT NULL THEN (CAST(DOID AS NVARCHAR(20)) +','+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20)))
                   END  
    where Quotation_T.QuotationID = 2 and Br_Code=1 and Item_Code=705
```

Comment: And in the second `THEN` clause too, otherwise the type of the `CASE` expression is `int` and you still get conversion errors.

Comment: Actually DOID already have a value 1...when i execute this query i got this error     Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int

Comment: if DOID is int datatype you cannot save chars  in it (or decimal number). I believe DOID is int data type.

Comment: @neethamathew are you trying to save an array of ids?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your DOID data type is int, and needs to be NVARCHAR(20) - (maybe NVARCHAR(max) would be better) to support characters.
Your update works fine if the DOID is NVARCHAR(20).

Here's what I see from testing.

```
create table Quotation_T
(
DOID nvarchar(20)
)

insert into Quotation_T VALUES(N'hello');
insert into Quotation_T VALUES(null);
insert into Quotation_T VALUES(N'2')

update Quotation_T  set DOID= CASE 
    WHEN DOID IS NULL THEN CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))
    WHEN DOID LIKE '%'+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))+'%' THEN DOID       
    WHEN DOID IS NOT NULL THEN (DOID +','+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20)))
END  

SELECT * from Quotation_T
/* results in
hello,2
2
2
*/

create table Quotation_Tint
(
DOID int
)

insert into Quotation_Tint VALUES(4);
insert into Quotation_Tint VALUES(null);
insert into Quotation_Tint VALUES(2)

update Quotation_Tint  set DOID= CASE 
    WHEN DOID IS NULL THEN CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))
    WHEN DOID LIKE '%'+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20))+'%' THEN DOID       
    WHEN DOID IS NOT NULL THEN (DOID +','+CAST(2 AS NVARCHAR(20)))
END  

SELECT * from Quotation_Tint
/* results in 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.
*/
```

Comment: It would obviously be helpful if you gave us the CREATE TABLE statement for Quotation_T